# DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->update($data); does not update data

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to update the data in the database. If I use `DB::table('users')->update($data)` it updates all the data but `DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update($data)` isn't updating the single row. How can I update a single row?

```
public function edit(Request $req,$id) {
  $id = $req->input('id');
  $name = $req->input('name');
      $email = $req->input('email') ;
      $data=array('name'=>$name,'email'=>$email) ;

      //DB::table('users')->update($data);

      DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->update($data);


      echo "data   recorded successfully.<br/>";
  }
    Route::get('/update','TestController@index_update')->name('display');
Route::get('edit/{id}','TestController@show')->name('updateD');
Route::post('/editt/{id}','TestController@edit')->name('updateEdit');;

<form  method="post" action = "{{route('updateEdit')}}" > 
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
               <td>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'name' value = "{{ $books[0]->name }}"/>
               </td>
               <td>email</td>
               <td>
                  <input type = 'text' name = 'email' 
                     value = "{{ $books[0]->email }}"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan = '2'>
                  <input type = 'submit' value = "Update student" />
               </td>
               </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
```

Comment: Could you include the result you're getting and the result you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your ID in your form

Try this one:

```
<form  method="post" action = "{{url('/editt/', $books[0]->id)}}" > 
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
               <td>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'name' value = "{{ $books[0]->name }}"/>
               </td>
               <td>email</td>
               <td>
                  <input type = 'text' name = 'email' 
                     value = "{{ $books[0]->email }}"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan = '2'>
                  <input type = 'submit' value = "Update student" />
               </td>
               </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
```

Even tho you're calling `$req->input('id')` I don't see anything like that in your form.

And simple tip always use `dd($req->all());` to check if your `REQUEST` is passing the right value for you and you know where you can start to debug. Check also if your id is passing by using `dd();` It will be always your friend.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your function body, you seem to be overwriting your url parameter named $id. So if there is no request body with name/key id, you might have a null ID before the query executes. Comment that line (line 2 in the function) and try again.

Comment: So do log the values u have for id, name and email and debug from there. Is it possible the id specified is not in the user's table?

Answer (score 0):

```
action = "{{route('updateEdit',['id'=>$books[0]->id])}}"
```